# Appending a value from a list to an empty list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

One list contains values and one is empty. I want to take out two values from the list with data and place it into the empty list using a for loop. I know how to get one value. However, I am not sure how to get the other. Here is my code below:

```
 all_fruits = ['apples', 'cherry', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'peach']
# The above list is a list of all fruits

# Now lets creat a blank list called favorite fruit
favorite_fruit = []

# The objective is to choose two fruits from the all fruits list and append them to the favorite fruit list

for fruit in all_fruits:
    if fruit == 'apples':
        favorite_fruit.append(fruit)



print favorite_fruit

Output: ['apples']
```

I want the `favorite_fruit` variable to output `['apples', 'peaches']` or `['apples', 'cherry']`. How do I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Add another if-statement

Comment: Get the index of apples and iterate from that index

Comment: how are you judging what your favorite fruit is? is it random? the first 2?

Comment: @depperm I think he needs the combination of those

Comment: Little tip: try to be consistent with your use of plural in variable names, otherwise one day you will drive yourself mad.

Comment: @Oliver. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add a condition in your for loop to detect the second favorite fruit.

```
for fruit in all_fruits:

    if fruit == 'apples' or fruit == 'peach':
        favorite_fruit.append(fruit)

print favorite_fruit

Output: ['apples', 'peach']
```

Or in general you can build your favorite fruit list as a filtered list of the initial one like so.

```
def is_a_favorite_fruit(fruit):
    return fruit == 'apples' or fruit == 'peach'

favorite_fruits = [fruit for fruit in all_fruits if is_a_favorite_fruit(fruit)]

print favorite_fruit

Output: ['apples', 'peach']
```

Comment: I understand that but when the favorite_fruit list is printed it only prints 'apples'. I want it to print the whole list of whatever is being appended. @Olivier

Comment: It will do so, it's just that you did not append anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loop and in one line:

```
all_fruits = ['apples', 'cherry', 'pear', 'strawberry', 'peach']

print(list(filter(lambda x:x=='apples' or x=='peach',all_fruits)))
```

output:

```
['apples', 'peach']
```